# A TCP Client thread with PyQt5

Tags: tcp, pyqt5, qthread

I am trying to create a TCP thread with QThread in PyQ5. Here is my code.I have 3 lineedits to read IP, Port and Buffer Size.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from TTP_Monitor_GUI import Ui_MainWindow

import socket
import sys

class WorkerObject(QObject):

    @pyqtSlot(str, int, int)
    def ListenTCP(self, TCP_IP, TCP_PORT,BUFFER_SIZE):
        # create a socket object
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # Bind the socket to the port
        server_address = (TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)
        #print(server_address)
        self.s.connect(server_address)

        # Look for the response
        while True:
            self.data = self.s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            #amount_received += len(self.data)
            print(self.data)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def StopTCP(self):
        print("STOP_TCP")
        print(self.data)
        self.s.close()
        print(self.data)

class Main(QMainWindow):

    SignalTCPStart = pyqtSignal()
    SignalTCPStop = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.worker = WorkerObject()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.ui.btnConnect.clicked.connect(self.ConnectToTCP)
        self.ui.btnDisconnect.clicked.connect(self.Disconnect)

    def ConnectToTCP(self):

        # set IP and Port
        TCP_IP = self.ui.txtIP.text()
        TCP_PORT = int(self.ui.txtPort.text())
        BUFFER_SIZE = int(self.ui.txtBuffer.text())

        self.SignalTCPStart.connect(self.worker.ListenTCP(TCP_IP, TCP_PORT,BUFFER_SIZE))

        # No harm in calling thread.start() after the thread is already started.
        self.thread.start()
        self.SignalTCPStart.emit()

    def Disconnect(self):
        self.SignalTCPStop.connect(self.worker.StopTCP)
        self.SignalTCPStop.emit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Main()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Software\TTP_Monitor\TTP_Monitor.py", line 65, in ConnectToTCP
    self.SignalTCPStart.connect(self.worker.ListenTCP(TCP_IP, TCP_PORT,BUFFER_SIZE))
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

Interestingly, without UI and QThread, while loop works perfectly. I can read the data but the code above gives this error.

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: `self.SignalTCPStart.connect(lambda: self.worker.ListenTCP(...))`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved the problem. However, the while loop freezes the GUI. Somehow, the thread is not working. Why?

Comment: It's because you are calling `ListenTCP` in the main thread. You should connect it to the thread's `started` signal instead (i.e. put `self.thread.started.connect( self.worker.ListenTCP)` in `__init__`). Obviously this means you will need a separate method to re-set the parameters on the worker before it starts. The `SignalTCPStart` signal is not needed at all.

Comment: I am trying to listen TCP after clicked the Connect button. In __init__ func, it starts but now the GUI does not show up. You are right I need to seperate method to set parameters before it starts. I am working on it. What do you suggest? Thanks...

Comment: I works fine for me. I don't know what you are doing wrong.